# Socket.io doesn't close connections when users close browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have a socket server (socket.io + nodejs) and a socket client (socket.io). The problem is that client connections remain opened also when users close the browser, creating an high number of dead connections.

For example, when I open the browser and run this command "lsof -i -n -P | grep node | grep ‘my ip address’" I have one connection. When I close the browser and run again that command, the connection remains opened.

Thanks a lot everyone wants to help me!

Comment: It remains open in what (TCP) state?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `socket.disconnect()`on the client side, this should work.

Connection shouldnt be **on** once either the server or client triggers **disconnect**. There must be some other issue in your code on the server side. 
Try using this to close connection on the server side

```
socket.on('terminate', function (){
    socket.disconnect(0);
});
```

And this on the client side:

```
var io = io();
io.emit('terminate');
```

See if it works out for you.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make ping-pong feature where server will broadcast `ping` event, and client-side must response with `pong`.
If during 10 seconds (in this example) server will not get `pong` event so garbage cleaner function will disconnect socket.

Server-side:

```
var aliveSockets = {};

// broadcasting ping
setInterval(function() {
  io.emit('ping', {timestamp: (new Date()).getTime()});
}, 10000); // 10 seconds

// cleaning up stalled socket which does not answer to ping
setInterval(function() {
  aliveSockets.forEach(function(aliveSocket, idx) {
    if(!aliveSocket) {return;}
    if(aliveSocket.lastPong + 10 < (new Date().getTime())/1000) {
      aliveSocket.socket.disconnect(0);
      delete aliveSocket[idx];
    }
  });
}, 1000); // 1 second

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  sockets[socket.id] = socket;

  socket.on('pong', function() {
    aliveSockets[socket.id] = {socket: socket, lastPong: ((new Date()).getTime()/1000)};
  });
});
```

Client-side:

```
io.on('ping', function() {
  io.emit('pong', {timestamp: (new Date()).getTime()});
});
```

**p.s. idea is just workaround, but I do prefer not to write ping-pong-ers, just trust to socket.io library, it will remove it after some time (~1 minute)**

read this: https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#methods-1  You can see it has `pingTimeout` that means socket.io will handle Your problem automatically.

> pingTimeout (Number): how many ms without a pong packet to consider
>   the connection closed (60000)

Comment: That's something that `socket.io` (or rather, the underlying `engine.io`) [already does](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#methods-1) (`pingTimeout` and `pingInterval`).

Comment: @robertklep You've no patience as everybody (: I was writing it, see changes in my answer.

Comment: Haha sorry, I'll try to be less quick next time ;)

Comment: @robertklep I understand Your speed of commenting (:  all of these I've wrote to show the question owner that it can be done like this, but it's already done by engine itself.

Comment: I wonder if the connections really remain open, or if they show up in a TCP state like `CLOSE_WAIT` (which would be normal). But haven't heard back from OP yet :(

Comment: Thanks for your help! Actually the connections remain really open and stable, I'm trying to modify my code with your advices, be ready to give me support again :)

Comment: I'm trying to use your code but doesn't work well and I don't understand what is happening.

This is the debug of NodeJs script: do you know what means 

"engine:socket sending packet "pong" (undefined) +0ms" ?

  engine:ws received "2" +25s
  engine:socket packet +0ms
  engine:socket got ping +1ms
  engine:socket sending packet "pong" (undefined) +0ms
  engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
  engine:ws writing "3" +0ms

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ale seems like You've put emit('pong') on server-side code (:  pong is response for emit('ping') from serverside. so be careful where You put Your code. You've 2 sides: 1. server-side, 2. client-side.  Server-side sends periodically "ping" messages, client-side must catch "ping" message and respond with "pong".

Comment: @Ale can you add the "before" and "after" output of `lsof` to your question?

Comment: I didn't write that ping-pong code, it is the native code of Socket.io. @num8er