# Ping Pong Socket.io doesn't work

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to solve this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053300/socket-io-doesnt-close-connections-when-users-close-browser) , something doesn't work well and I don't understand what is happening.

This is the debug output of the server script:

```
engine:ws received "2" +25s
engine:socket packet +0ms
engine:socket got ping +1ms
engine:socket sending packet "pong" (undefined) +0ms
engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
engine:ws writing "3" +0ms
```

What does `engine:socket sending packet "pong" (undefined) +0ms` mean?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `sockets`, on a programming level, are not `socket.io` related... I replaced the tag with the correct one. See the [tag:sockets] tag details for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` is the data of the packet, which is undefined.

The default ping/pong mechanism of `socket.io` causes this, and it's normal.